# I can't get the column max values from my csv file.(Javascript D3)

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

So I'm trying to make a scatter plot graph that takes input from 2 drop down menus. Once the choices are made, that'll choose 2 of the columns in the csv file.

However, the max values vary between the choices, so i need the program to change with the varying choices made by the user. So in the snippet of code which is going to be responsible for it, I feel that the syntax makes sense. The end result is that I tried storing the results in 2 separate variables and printing to the console, and the results come out as "undefined", but no errors. So I'm not sure where the issue is coming from. If i hard code the columns and axis for any singular choice, the points show up no problem. But because I've set it dynamically, there aren't any values being captured I guess. Any help is appreciated.

```
d3.csv("datafile.csv",function(data){
var xMx = d3.max(data,function(d) { return d.xvalue; } );
var yMx = d3.max(data,function(d) { return d.yvalue; } );
console.log(xMx);[enter image description here][1]
//x-axis
var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,xMx])
```

The version is:4.13.0
I've tried including the csv file.https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq8Aq.jpg

Comment: Please share your CSV, just the header and one or two rows. Also, what's the D3 version?

Comment: Your CSV does not contain `xvalue` nor `yvalue`. Where do you expect those to come from? `data` is an array of objects containing properties matching the CSV's column names...

Comment: I'm aware of the variables not existing in the file, the reason I used those values was because those were the arguments from the main method that put the actual column names in. Since I can't explicitly choose which column to search the max values in, I'm having issues trying to get the input directly without having to resort to if statements. If i do, it'll be a bunch of combinations of 'if' statements which would be responsible for difference scaling axes per column and that becomes even more convoluted.

Comment: So, `xvalue` and `yvalue` are holding the actual names of the columns you are interested in, is that correct? In that case, you need what is called bracket notation, i.e. `d[xvalue]` and `d[<value]`, instead of dot notation (`d.xvalue`) to access the properties of those names. Related: [*"Fetch value using input from user in D3"*](/q/36009890).

Answer (score 0):

`d3.csv()` does not automatically convert strings to numbers. I would recommend reading in the data, using `d3.csv()`’s `row` argument to properly handle the data, and only then finding the max using `d3.max()`’s accessor.

Since you’re using D3 4, it’d be something like

```
d3.csv("datafile.csv", r => {
    // this function returns a new object for each row.
    // the + is common shorthand for parseFloat()

    return {
        xvalue: +r.xvalue,
        yvalue: +r.yvalue
    };
}, data => {
    let xMx = d3.max(data, d => d.xvalue);
    let yMx = d3.max(data, d => d.yvalue);
    console.log(xMx, yMx);
});
```